# Permanently identifying media device in webrtc application

Tags: javascript, cookies, webrtc

I have a web application with a basic video chat implementation with OpenTok. Right now i have a select that enables the user to switch audio and video devices.

I would like to uniquely identify devices based on their IDs and save them in the database to be able to switch them automatically.

Searching around, i found the Javascript [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo) specs, but it says that the `MediaDeviceInfo.deviceId`:

> Returns a DOMString that is an identifier for the represented device 
>   that is persisted across sessions. It is un-guessable by other 
>   applications and unique to the origin of the calling application. It 
>   is reset when the user clears cookies (for Private Browsing, a 
>   different identifier is used that is not persisted across sessions).

So i can't rely on this, because if the user clears the cookie i have to remap every device.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Try the user experience in Hangouts device selection, we can't do anything more than them. Its the matter of user privacy.